# Bitcoin core: connect to specific peers from file

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, peers

I want to launch Bitcoin core connecting to a specific list of peers. I can do this using `connect`:

`bitcoind -connect=<IP1> -connect=<IP2>`

Is there a way I can put the peers I want to connect to into a file and give this file to `bitcoind` as input?

Comment: You can put them in the bitcoin.conf file, but I'm guessing that's not what you mean. Simply multiple lines with: connect=IP

Comment: @Jannes "put them in the bitcoin.conf file" -- why not? Will the effect be as described?

Comment: Yeah it will work fine. I was just assuming you were getting some computer generated dynamic list from somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within the data directory for your coin (/dir/for/yourcoin/.yourcoin) you will have a configuration file. Within this configuration file, you will want to place the line connect=IP ADDRESS:PORT

This will make your client automatically attempt to establish a connection with the node(s) you specify.

Example: within myaltcoin.conf place the line connect=192.168.49.50:9332
Obviously just substitute your desired IP address and port.